# UV mapping rendering wrong

Tags: uv

When I render my UV mapped object it shows fine in the design stage but the rendering looks very wrong. What is happening and how do I fix this?

[image: pallet1][image: pallet2]

Comment: Please show your material settings in a screen image. Please show your textures that are attached to your material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your texture setting in the material panel.  Try being in render mode rather than texture mode.  The render mode and texture mode can show different results.

On the texture panel. Select type Image. Open the image. Select Mapping UV Map.

Comment: The issue was that coordinates was not set to UV!